# C Program not recognizing global variables

Tags: c, global-variables, global

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvfZI.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VCPd.jpg)

I declared some global variables in c but I am getting these errors and I don't know what they mean, can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow. Please, do not post images of your code. This makes it very time consuming for us to help you because we would have to re-type all your code, whereas you could make it easy to copy and paste for us. Also, we should not be expected to have to go off-site (even to an image hosting webpage) in order to understand your question; your question and all details needed to understand it should be contained within the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gcc test2.c` and `./a.out`
Instead of `./ test2.c`

install mingw and run `./a.exe` in Windows.